# Burton Archimedean property proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Can anyone help me understand the following proof of Archimedean property in Burton's Elementary Number Theory book:

> Theorem 1.1  Archimedean  property.  If  $a$  and  $b$  are  any 
>   positive  integers,  then  there  exists  a positive  integer  $n$ 
>   such  that  $na  \ge    b$.  Proof.  Assume  that  the  statement  of 
>   the  theorem  is not  true,  so  that  for  some  $a$  and  $b$,  $na <  b$  for  every  positive  integer  n.  Then  the  set  $S =  \{b- na  |  n$  a positive  integer$\}$  consists  entirely  of  positive  integers.  By  the  Well-Ordering  Principle,  $S$  will 
>   possess  a  least  element,  say,  $b- ma$.  Notice  that  $b- (m +  1)a$  also  lies  in $S$,  because  $S$  contains  all  integers  of  this  form.  Furthermore,  we  have  $b- (m +  1)a =  (b- ma)- a<  b- ma$  contrary  to  the  choice  of  $b - ma$  as  the  smallest  integer  in  $S$.  This  contradiction  arose  out  of  our  original  assumption  that  the  Archimedean 
>   property  did  not  hold;  hence,  this  property  is proven  true.

If he defined $b-ma$ as the least element of the set then how can he define another even lesser element $b-(m+1)a$? Wouldn't that mean that would be a negative number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Eventually* it means that $b-(m+1)a$ is negative, but the fact that you "know" this is jumping ahead a bit.  The assumption is that $na<b$ for every positive integer $n$.  That has to include $n=m+1$, so you're assuming $(m+1)a<b$ which is to say $b-(m+1)a >0.$  This leads to a contradiction and then you can conclude that $b-(m+1)a$ is negative.  You're letting your intuition get aheas of your logic.

Comment: So essentially what this proves is that as long as $n$ can be any positive integer then we can keep choosing greater and greater $n$ to reduce further, therefore contradicting the fact that this set contains a least element, i.e. that it contains negative numbers as well. Is that about right?

Comment: I'd say it's about right.  Taking such intuition and making a rigorous proof out of it is the main game in math.

Comment: Hmm, can you please tell me why was set of $b-na$ chosen as a counterexample?

Comment: The _set_ isn't a counterexample, but the least element gives you a counterexample.  IF there is no such $n$ THEN this is a set of positive integers and therefore must have a least element.  But you show that there is no least element without violating your original assumption, therefore the original assumption is wrong.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is why was that specific set chosen in the proof. Can any other set be used? How did the author decide to choose that set to continue the proof?

Comment: I doubt i a different set would work.  The author was probably thinking, "I need to show that there's some $n$ so that $na>b$....or perhaps that $na - b$ is postive.  Hmmm..  so what if all $na-b$ are negative...or all $b-an$ positive...".